# If on my machine sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long), why aren't they the same type?

Tags: c++, types, 64-bit, int64, long-long

If I run:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(long) = " << sizeof(long) << "\n";
    std::cout << "sizeof(long long) = " << sizeof(long long) << "\n";
    std::cout << "std::is_same<long, long long>::value = " 
        << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<long, long long>::value 
        << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

on my machine (and on Coliru), I [get](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/057296f7d741dc5e):

```
sizeof(long) = 8
sizeof(long long) = 8
std::is_same<long, long long>::value = false
```

And it isn't just `std::is_same<>`; translation units expecting an instantiation for `int64_t` fail because I only compiled for `int` and `long long int` in another translation unit, despite it all happening on the same machine.

Why aren't these types the same? I mean, exhibiting behavior like you would have from `typedef`'s of the same type?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this question. It contains a compilable example, and expected and documented output. Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @Bathsheba Not a down voter but I find it silly.  `long` and `long long` are different types called out by the standard so it makes sense that `std::is_same` returns false.  Others might have felt the same.

Comment: I agree with Nathan, they are just simply different types.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You found it silly by circular reasoning. My question is why they're different and you're telling me "they're different because they are".

Comment: IMHO the degree of obviousness should not be a factor in downvoting. Questions on General Relativity are obvious to my old professor.

Comment: @I'mhereforWinterHats: It's anything but "just simply". They're entirely identical in size and semantics. Why should they not just be aliases of each other depending on the machine sizes?

Comment: `char` is either signed or unsigned, but `char` is neither `signed char` nor `unsigned char`. `wchar_t` must be a distinct type instead of another integral type

Comment: @einpoklum as Bathsheba said it's a language rule, so it is simple you follow it. You work with the grain not against it.

Comment: @einpoklum Because they are built in types.  No built in type is an alias of another type.  The implementation might use the same thing but as far as the code is concerned they are distinct.  The standard give a lot of leeway in how the built in types are actually implemented.

Comment: @I'mhereforWinterHats: Sure, ok, but that's not a reason to downvote the question. The language could well have had no such rule, it's not crucial for anything (that I know of).

Comment: @einpoklum Who said I did, I said I agreed with what Nathan said?

Comment: @I'mhereforWinterHats: Ah, sorry. Then - pretend I was answering a theoretical argument from a downvoter :-)

Comment: Why aren't `bool` and `char` the same type? Or `float[2]` and `double`? How about `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<std::string>`? Two things are not the same type just because they have the same size :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd add `char` and `struct my_char { char c; };`, they have the same size on my laptop but they are not the same type. Damnit.

Comment: What we are essentially saying here is that size does not matter.

Comment: @Bathsheba: You're saying that size is not everything...

Comment: @skypjack: But struct is not a basic type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the language rule and crucial for portability.

`int`, `long`, and `long long` are all treated as different types by the language, even if they have the same number of bytes and complement scheme.

This is intentional. It means that you can write code that can compile on different platforms where the size of the types vary.

It would be very annoying if say for example, two overloads

```
void foo(int f)
```

and

```
void foo(long f)
```

were treated as the same function on one platform, and different overloads on another.

Comment: It might compile, but it might also do something other than what I expected it... writing code for machines with different sizes is tricky anyway. But, well, what can I say, that's the answer I guess.

Comment: @einpoklum if they were the same type, writing the two overloads would be a violation of the one definition rule (because really it would be one overload written two different ways). This would result in a compilation error on some platforms and not on others. This would be unacceptable in every way.

Comment: @RichardHodges: On the other hand, the way things stand now you can't cover all of the integer types with `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t` and `int64_t`.

Comment: @einpoklum: I'm not sure that's relevant. The fixed width signed types all demand 2's complement. The built in types I've stated can be 1's complement, 2's complement or signed magnitude. C++ is designed to target exotic architectures.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That's actually an interesting point which makes it more obvious why size and signedness are not sufficient to determine an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, this program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using ::std::cout;
    using ::std::is_same;
    using ::std::boolalpha;

    cout << "sizeof(long) = " << sizeof(long) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(long long) = " << sizeof(long long) << "\n";
    cout << "sizeof(double) = " << sizeof(double) << "\n";
    cout << "::std::is_same<long, long long>::value = " 
        << boolalpha << is_same<long, long long>::value 
        << "\n";
    std::cout << "::std::is_same<long, double>::value = " 
        << boolalpha << is_same<long, double>::value 
        << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs this:

```
sizeof(long) = 8
sizeof(long long) = 8
sizeof(double) = 8
::std::is_same<long, long long>::value = false
::std::is_same<long, double>::value = false
```

As you can see, `double` and `long` appear to be the same length, why aren't they just typedefs of the same type?

Comment: These types don't have the same semantics. An 8-byte `long` behaves  exactly the same (as an integer, I mean) as an 8-byte `long long`.

Comment: @einpoklum, yes, that is a difference. Though, I would argue that they don't have _exactly_ the same semantics due to the overloading differences and such.